# Is this 1st order homogeneous ordinary differential equation analytically solvable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It is an equation about the quantities $\{ \psi_n | -\infty < n < \infty \}$.

$$ i \frac{ \partial \psi_n}{\partial t}  = - (\psi_{n-1} + \psi_{n+1} ) + V\sin (\omega t)  \delta_{n,0}  \psi_0 .  $$

Here $\delta_{n,0} $ is the standard Kronecker function. $V $ and $\omega $ are constants.

This seems a very simple equation, right?

Is it possible to solve it in closed form? Or, at least get the qualitative behavior?

A particular initial condition is $\psi_n(t = 0 ) = \delta_{n, 0 } $.

Comment: Where does this come from?

Comment: This is a Schrodinger equation in physics

Comment: Do you mean $\sin(\omega t)$?  And what are the subscripts doing on the Dirac delta?  Are you sure it's not the Kronecker delta rather than the Dirac?

Comment: Sure. Yes, it is more appropriate to call it the Kronecker function.

Comment: That's a strange Schrödinger equation, is this being solved on a periodic lattice of sorts?

Comment: Exactly. On a lattice.